# How to remove the first part of a string in MySQL up to and including the first comma?

Tags: mysql, substring

A field in one of my MySQL tables contains a comma separated list of URLs to jpg images. I want to remove the first URL in the list, up to and including the first comma.

I have found a lot of examples of removing from the end of the list or removing the first x amount of characters from the front of the list. The problem here is that the list can contain between two and one hundred comma separated URLs and all the URLs can vary in length.

An example of the contents of this field might look like:

http://foo.com/51623/gfhfksdf/5956s/00.jpg,http://foo.com/51623/gfhfksdf/5956s/00.jpg,http://foo.com/51623/gfhfksdf/5956s/01.jpg,http://foo.com/51623/gfhfksdf/5956s/02.jpg,http://foo.com/51623/gfhfksdf/5956s/03.jpg

I only want to remove the first URL in the list and the first comma.

Comment: use `INSTR` and `REPLACE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all URLs are comma separated, you most likely need something like this

```
SELECT SUBSTR(ColumnName,LOCATE(',',ColumnName)+1) 
FROM YourTable;
```

OR

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE(Column_Name,SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnName,',',1),''),2)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm running it on import and want to update the table without the first URL in each list, so I wrote it like this to run after import.    update columnName set columnName = SUBSTR(columnName,LOCATE(',',columnName)+1) ;    Works great!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'https://google.com,https://youtube.com' as url, SUBSTRING(url, POSITION("," IN url)+1)
```

it will help you in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myvar varchar(100)

set @myvar:= 'wantedtoremovethisurl.combeforethecomma,showthistextthough'

select replace(@myvar,left(@myvar,instr(@myvar,',')),'')
```

You'll have to work it out if there is no comma